Issues in Reproducing Rippling Instability of Graphene using Mathematica from Physical Review B 101, 235428 (2020)
I'm attempting to reproduce the numerical model of the rippling instability of graphene as described in the paper "Physical Review B 101, 235428 (2020)" using Mathematica. Specifically, I'm trying to replicate the results shown in Figure 4a and 4b. My implementation follows the three main parts outlined below:
Part I: Setting up the Geometry

Choose parameter n to be 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16,...,22,..., 28,...,34 (i.e. n such that Mod[-2*n,3,1]==1) to have red top left edge. This is desirable.
Periodicity condition: Case n even (i.e Mod[n,2]==0) and also Mod[-2*n,3,1]==1 for red top left edge
Introduce scaling parameter, k, $k=a/a_0$

Clear["Global`*"]

(*Geometric parameters*)
nn = 16; (*distance center to edge in units of d (NN interatomic \
distance)*)
d := k  1.42; (*d (NN interatomic distance)*)
a := Sqrt[3]  k  1.42;

hextrans[{i_, j_}] := d*{Sqrt[3]/2  (i + j), 1/2 (j - i)}
ColSwitch[{x_, y_}] := {Red, Blue, White}[[Mod[x - y, 3, 1]]]

(*Lattice construction*)
AllIndex = 
  Join[Flatten[Table[Table[{i, j}, {j, -nn, nn - i}], {i, 0, nn}], 1],
    Flatten[
    Table[Table[{i, j} + {-0, 0}, {j, -nn - i, nn}], {i, -nn, 0}], 1]];
VarIndex = 
  AllIndex /. {i_, j_} /; Mod[i - j, 3, 1] == 3 :> 
    Nothing; (*remove white atoms*)
VarIndex = 
  VarIndex /. {i_, j_} /; (j == nn || i == -nn || i + j == nn) :> 
    Nothing;(*remove edges hexagon*)
Length@VarIndex

(*Periodic Boundary Conditions*)
B = {2*nn {-1/2, 1}, 2*nn {1/2, 1/2}};
Table[PBC[index + ind1*B[[1]] + ind2*B[[2]]] = index, {index, 
   VarIndex}, {ind1, -1, 1, 1}, {ind2, -1, 1, 1}];

(*Lattice plots with PBC*)
k = 1;
Graphics[{Riffle[ColSwitch /@ VarIndex, 
   Point[hextrans[#]] & /@ VarIndex],(*Text[Style[ToString@#,8],
  hextrans[#]]&/@Flatten[Table[Table[{i,j},{j,-n,n-i}],{i,0,n}],1],*)
  Text[Style[ToString@#, 3], hextrans[#] + {0, 0.4}] & /@ VarIndex, 
  Riffle[ColSwitch /@ VarIndex, Point[hextrans[#]] & /@ VarIndex]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {d*{-1.1*nn, 1.1*nn}, d*{-nn, nn}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 2/2.2]

Part II Discretised Differential Operators
Choose energetic parameter

Define Operators acting on displacement fields $\{u_x,u_y,h\}$. Corrected from typos

T /@ {ux,uy,h}
H /@ {ux,uy,h}
D /@ {ux,uy,h}
Dx /@ {ux,uy,h}
Dy /@ {ux,uy,h}
B /@ {ux,uy,h}
uii


Define Operator acting on local electronic occupations $\delta n(x,y)=n-1$. Needs electronic Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$

Dx @ {dn}
Dy @ {dn}


Scaling of energy paramters

$\ ( \mu, \lambda \ ) \to \ ( \mu, \lambda \ )  /k^2 $
$t \to t/k $
$\kappa, g$ not scaled with $k$



Note: neglect cosine $n$ i.e., $n=\frac{z_i-z_j}{R_{ij}} \approx 0$ in Slater-Koster Tight-Binding Hamiltonian $<i|\hat{H}|j>=(1-n^2) V_{pp\pi}\approx V_{pp\pi} \approx -2.7$ eV.
(*Energetic parameters - T. Cea Paper at T=0 K*)
\[Mu] := 9.44/k^2; (*eV/A^2*)
\[Lambda] := 3.25/k^2; (*eV/A^2*)
\[Kappa] := 0.82; (*eV*)
t := 2.70/k; (*eV*)
g0 := gfac*2.7; (*eV*)
Sgrapk := areagrap*k^2

(*Neighbours in order 1,2,3,....,9, see Fig. 7 *)
vlist = {# - {0, -1} & /@ {{0, -2}, {1, -1}, {-1, 
     0}, {1, -3}, {2, -2}, {-1, -2}, {1, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-1, 
     1}},(*Red center*)# - {1, -1} & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, -1}, {2, -2}, {0,
      1}, {-1, 0}, {2, 
     0}, {0, -2}, {3, -2}, {2, -3}} (*Blue center*)}; Table[
 v[i, j] = vlist[[i, j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 9}];

(*T op-Red||Blue sublattices*)
TOp[var_][{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 1]]], n] + 
    var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 2]]], n] + 
    var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 3]]], n] - 3*var[PBC[{x, y}], n] /. 
   col -> Mod[x - y, 3, 1] // ReleaseHold

(*H op-Red||Blue sublattices*)
HOp[var_][{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 6]]], n] + 
    var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 7]]], n] - 2*var[PBC[{x, y}], n] /. 
   col -> Mod[x - y, 3, 1] // ReleaseHold

(*D op-Red||Blue sublattices*)
DOp[var_][{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 4]]], n] + 
    var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 9]]], n] - 
    var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 5]]], n] - 
    var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 8]]], n] /. col -> Mod[x - y, 3, 1] //
   ReleaseHold

(*Dx op-Red||Blue sublattices*)
DxOp[var_][{x_, y_}, 
  n_] := (-1)^(col - 1)  (var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 2]]], n] - 
      var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 1]]], n]) /. 
   col -> Mod[x - y, 3, 1] // ReleaseHold

(*Dy op-Red||Blue sublattices*)
DyOp[var_][{x_, y_}, 
  n_] := (-1)^(col - 1)  1/
     2  (var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 3]]], n] + var[PBC[{x, y}], n] -
       var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 1]]], n] - 
      var[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 2]]], n]) /. 
   col -> Mod[x - y, 3, 1] // ReleaseHold

(*B op-Red||Blue sublattices*)
BOp[var_][{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 TOp[var][PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 1]]], n] + 
    TOp[var][PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 2]]], n] + 
    TOp[var][PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[col, 3]]], n] - 
    3*TOp[var][PBC[{x, y}], n] /. col -> Mod[x - y, 3, 1] // 
  ReleaseHold

(*G op@ux-Red||Blue sublattices*)
GOp[ux][{x_, y_}, 
  n_] := -1/
    2*(-(((-1)^Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*
           g0*(dn[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
             dn[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n]))/
         a) + (4*(-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 
           1]*\[Mu]*(h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], 
            n] - h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], 
            n])*(-3*h[{x, y}, n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n]))/
       a - ((-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 
           1]*\[Lambda]*(h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]],
             n] - h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], 
            n])*(2*h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n]))/
       a - (2*(-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 
           1]*\[Mu]*(h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], 
            n] - h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n])*(2*
            h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n]))/
       a - ((-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*\[Lambda]*(h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n])*(h[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/(2*
         a) - ((-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*\[Mu]*(h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n])*(h[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/(2*a) - 
      4*\[Mu]*ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
      4*\[Mu]*ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] - 
      4*\[Mu]*ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], 
        n] - \[Lambda]*
       ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
      2*\[Mu]*ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], 
        n] - \[Lambda]*
       ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n] - 
      2*\[Mu]*ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], 
        n] - (\[Lambda]*(uy[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/
       Sqrt[3] - (\[Mu]*(uy[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/
       Sqrt[3])/(\[Lambda] + 8*\[Mu]) // ReleaseHold

(*Gop mean@ux-Lagrange mulitplier workaround*)
GOpM[ux][n_] := GOpM[ux][n] = GOp[ux][#, n] & /@ VarIndex // Mean;

(*G op@uy-Red||Blue sublattices*)
GOp[uy][{x_, y_}, 
  n_] := -1/
    2*(((-1)^Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*Sqrt[3]*
         g0*(dn[{x, y}, n] - 
           dn[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           dn[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           dn[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n]))/(2*
         a) + (2*(-1)^Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*
         Sqrt[3]*\[Lambda]*(3*h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], 
            n])*(h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n]))/
       a + (2*(-1)^Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*
         Sqrt[3]*\[Mu]*(3*h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], 
            n])*(h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n]))/
       a - ((-1)^Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*
         Sqrt[3]*\[Lambda]*(h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n])*(2*
            h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n]))/(2*
         a) + ((-1)^Mod[x - y, 3, 1]*
         Sqrt[3]*\[Mu]*(h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n])*(2*
            h[{x, y}, n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n]))/
       a + ((-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 
           1]*\[Lambda]*(h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]],
             n] - h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], 
            n])*(h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/(Sqrt[
          3]*a) + ((-1)^
          Mod[x - y, 3, 
           1]*\[Mu]*(h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], 
            n] - h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n])*(h[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/(Sqrt[
          3]*a) - (\[Lambda]*(ux[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/
       Sqrt[3] - (\[Mu]*(ux[
            PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
           ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
           ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] + 
           ux[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n]))/
       Sqrt[3] - 
      4*\[Lambda]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
      4*\[Mu]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] - 
      4*\[Lambda]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] - 
      4*\[Mu]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] - 
      4*\[Lambda]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n] - 
      4*\[Mu]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], 
        n] + \[Lambda]*
       uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
      2*\[Mu]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], 
        n] + \[Lambda]*
       uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n] - 
      2*\[Mu]*uy[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], 
        n])/(5*\[Lambda] + 8*\[Mu]) // ReleaseHold

(*Gop mean@uy-Lagrange mulitplier workaround*)
GOpM[uy][n_] := GOpM[uy][n] = GOp[uy][#, n] & /@ VarIndex // Mean;

(*G op@h-Red||Blue sublattices*)
GOp[h][{x_, y_}, 
  n_] := (288*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 1]]], n] + 
     288*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 2]]], n] + 
     288*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 3]]], n] - 
     48*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 4]]], n] - 
     48*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 5]]], n] - 
     48*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 6]]], n] - 
     48*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 7]]], n] - 
     48*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 8]]], n] - 
     48*a^2*\[Kappa]*
      h[PBC[Hold[{x, y} + v[Mod[x - y, 3, 1], 9]]], n] + 
     Sqrt[3]*a*\[Lambda]*DOp[uy][{x, y}, n]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     Sqrt[3]*a*\[Mu]*DOp[uy][{x, y}, n]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n] - 
     3*g0*DxOp[dn][{x, y}, n]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     2*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Mu]*DOp[h][{x, y}, n]*DxOp[uy][{x, y}, n] + 
     3*a*\[Lambda]*DOp[ux][{x, y}, n]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     3*a*\[Mu]*DOp[ux][{x, y}, n]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*\[Lambda]*DOp[h][{x, y}, n]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]*
      DyOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*\[Mu]*DOp[h][{x, y}, n]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]*
      DyOp[h][{x, y}, n] - 
     9*g0*DyOp[dn][{x, y}, n]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*a*\[Mu]*DOp[h][{x, y}, n]*DyOp[ux][{x, y}, n] + 
     3*\[Lambda]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*HOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*\[Mu]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*HOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*a*\[Mu]*DxOp[ux][{x, y}, n]*HOp[h][{x, y}, n] - 
     9*\[Lambda]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*HOp[h][{x, y}, n] - 
     18*\[Mu]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*HOp[h][{x, y}, n] - 
     6*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Mu]*DyOp[uy][{x, y}, n]*HOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     3*a*\[Lambda]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]*HOp[ux][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*a*\[Mu]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]*HOp[ux][{x, y}, n] - 
     3*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Lambda]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]*HOp[uy][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Mu]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]*HOp[uy][{x, y}, n] - 
     12*g0*dn[{x, y}, n]*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     6*\[Lambda]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*\[Mu]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*a*\[Lambda]*DxOp[ux][{x, y}, n]*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     54*\[Lambda]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     108*\[Mu]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Lambda]*DyOp[uy][{x, y}, n]*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     24*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Mu]*DyOp[uy][{x, y}, n]*TOp[h][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*a*\[Mu]*DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]*TOp[ux][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Lambda]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]*TOp[uy][{x, y}, n] + 
     12*Sqrt[3]*a*\[Mu]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n]*TOp[uy][{x, y}, n])/(576*
     a^2*\[Kappa]) // ReleaseHold

(*Gop mean@h-Lagrange mulitplier workaround*)
GOpM[h][n_] := GOpM[h][n] = GOp[h][#, n] & /@ VarIndex // Mean;

(*strain Op-*)
uii[{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 uii[{x, y}, n] = 
  1/a  (DxOp[ux][{x, y}, n] + Sqrt[3]*DyOp[uy][{x, y}, n]) + 
   1/(2  a^2)  (DxOp[h][{x, y}, n]^2 + (Sqrt[3]*DyOp[h][{x, y}, n])^2)

(*Hamiltonian part and electron occupation*)
Rgrh[n_] := 
  Rgrh[n] = 
   Table[Flatten@{hextrans[i], 0} + {ux[i, n], uy[i, n], h[i, n]}, {i,
      VarIndex}];
dist[n_][i_, j_] := Norm[Rgrh[n][[i]] - Rgrh[n][[j]]];
Htb[n_] := 
  Htb[n] = 
   Table[If[0.9*d < dist[n][i, j] < 0.9*Sqrt[3]*d, -t (*(1-(dz[i,j]/d[
      i,j])^2)*), 0], {i, 1, Length@Rgrh[n]}, {j, 1, 
      Length@Rgrh[n]}] - 
    g0*DiagonalMatrix[Table[uii[index, n], {index, VarIndex}]];
eigen[n_] := 
  eigen[n] = 
   Eigensystem[Htb[n]]; (*eigenvals are real-Hermitian Hamiltonian*)
mu[n_] := 
  mu[n] = (Sort@(eigen[n][[1]]))[[Floor[(Length@VarIndex)/
       2]]];(*Median[eigen[n][[1]]];chemical potential*)
(*T=0 K energy filling*)
nsitelist[n_] := 
  nsitelist[n] = 
   Table[Total[(eigen[n][[2]])[[;; , 
        pos]]  Conjugate[(eigen[n][[2]])[[;; , 
         pos]]]  ((eigen[n][[1]]) /. {x_ /; (Re@x <= mu[n]) -> 2, 
         x_ /; (Re@x > mu[n]) -> 0})], {pos, 1, Length@Rgrh[n]}];
dn[{x_, y_}, 
  n_] := ((nsitelist[
      n])[[Flatten[Position[VarIndex, PBC@{x, y}]][[1]]]] - 1)


(*total energy*)
(*Elastic deformation energy*)
Felastic[n_] := 
 3  Sqrt[3]/
   4  a^2  Sum[\[Kappa]  ((4/a^2  TOp[h][poslist, 
          n])^2) + \[Lambda]  uii[poslist, n]^2 + 
    2  \[Mu]   ((1/a  DxOp[ux][poslist, n] + 
          1/2  (1/a  DxOp[h][poslist, n])^2)^2 + (Sqrt[3]/a  DyOp[uy][
            poslist, n] + 
          1/2  (Sqrt[3]/a  DyOp[h][poslist, n])^2)^2 + 
       2*(Sqrt[3]/2*DyOp[ux][poslist, n]/a + 
           1/2*DxOp[uy][poslist, n]/a + 
           1/2*Sqrt[3]/a^2*DxOp[h][poslist, n]*
            DyOp[h][poslist, n])^2), {poslist, VarIndex}]

(*Electronic energy*)
Felectronic[n_] := 
 eigen[n][[1]]  ((eigen[n][[1]]) /. {x_ /; (Re@x <= mu[n]) -> 2, 
      x_ /; (Re@x > mu[n]) -> 0}) // Total
Ftotal[n_] := Felastic[n] + Felectronic[n]

Part III SOR algorithm / Memoization module

Choose relaxation parameter $\omega$

Initial values for displacement fields

ux[{x,y},0]
uy[{x,y},0]
h[{x,y},0]


Evaluate error at each iteration to check convergence


Code
(*SOR algorithm parameters*)
\[Omega] = 0.1;

(*algorithm without GOp-averages*)
ux[{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 ux[{x, y}, 
   n] = (1 - \[Omega])  ux[{x, y}, 
     n - 1] + \[Omega]*(GOp[ux][{x, y}, n - 1])
uy[{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 uy[{x, y}, 
   n] = (1 - \[Omega])  uy[{x, y}, 
     n - 1] + \[Omega]*(GOp[uy][{x, y}, n - 1])
h[{x_, y_}, n_] := 
 h[{x, y}, 
   n] = (1 - \[Omega])  h[{x, y}, 
     n - 1] + \[Omega]*(GOp[h][{x, y}, n - 1])

(*starting vals*)
(*5 a/k for case 533 atoms*)
(*change a/k for a in the Eq.below*)
h[{i_, j_}, 0] := 
 1*a/k*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/((nn/2)^2*d^2)] /. 
  Thread[{x, y} -> hextrans[PBC[{i, j}]]]
ux[{i_, j_}, 0] := 0 /. Thread[{x, y} -> hextrans[PBC[{i, j}]]]
uy[{i_, j_}, 0] := 0 /. Thread[{x, y} -> hextrans[PBC[{i, j}]]]

(*strain error*)
error[n_] := 
 error[n] = Max[Abs[uii[#, n] - uii[#, n - 1]] & /@ VarIndex]

Finally let's solve the equations and plot the results for comparing with Figures 4a and 4b in the paper:
SDpcent[gfacnum_, knum_, 
  nend_] := ((*Clear stuff memoization*)
   Table[Rgrh[iterations] =.  ux[coor, iterations] =.; 
    uy[coor, iterations] =.; h[coor, iterations] =.;
    error[iterations] =.; dn[coor, iterations] =.; 
    nsitelist[iterations] =.;
    mu[iterations] =.; eigen[iterations] =.; Htb[iterations] =.; 
    uii[coor, iterations] =.;
    GOpM[ux][iterations] =.; GOpM[uy][iterations] =.; 
    GOpM[h][iterations] =.;, {iterations, 1, nend}, {coor, 
     VarIndex}];
   (*asign g factor*)gfac = gfacnum; k = knum;
   (*compute S[%]*)(*scale error by k or not?*)
   Sval = (uii[#, nend]^2 & /@ VarIndex) // Mean // Sqrt // 100  # &;
   (*calculate h[0] from local mean hcen=(h[#,nend]&/@VarCenIndex)//
   Mean;
   h2=((h[#,nend]-hcen)^2&/@VarEdgeIndex)//Mean;*)
   h2 = ((h[#, nend])^2 & /@ VarIndex) // Mean;
   {error[nend]/knum, Sval, Ftotal[nend], h2}) // Quiet

MaxIter = 7;
klist = {30, 50, 100, 300, 1000};
SDdata = 
  Table[Flatten@{gval, SDpcent[gval, kval, MaxIter]}, {kval, 
    klist}, {gval, 0, 20, 0.5}];
(*An average strain error of 0.1 roughly corresponds to 10 % change \
in deformation*)(*Add dates for output files*)
dateoutput = "24-Jul-2024"
Splot1 = 
  Table[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ SDdata[[i]], {i, 1, Length@SDdata}];
Splot2 = 
  Table[{#[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ SDdata[[i]], {i, 1, Length@SDdata}];
Splot3 = 
  Table[{#[[1]], (#[[4]] - SDdata[[i, 1, -2]])/
       Abs[SDdata[[i, 1, -2]]]} & /@ SDdata[[i]], {i, 1, 
    Length@SDdata}];
Splot4 = 
  Table[{#[[1]], #[[5]]} & /@ SDdata[[i]], {i, 1, Length@SDdata}];


{ListPlot[Splot1, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"g/t", "error [-]"}, 
  PlotLegends -> ("k=" <> ToString@# & /@ klist), 
  PlotLabel -> "\[CapitalDelta]Strain"], 
 ListPlot[Splot2, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"g/t", "S[%]"}, 
  PlotLegends -> ("k=" <> ToString@# & /@ klist), 
  PlotLabel -> "Deformation"], 
 ListPlot[Splot3, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {-4, 0}, Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {"g/t", "D[-]"}, 
  PlotLegends -> ("k=" <> ToString@# & /@ klist), 
  PlotLabel -> "Energy"], 
 ListPlot[Splot4, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"g/t", "<h^2>"}, 
  PlotLegends -> ("k=" <> ToString@# & /@ klist), 
  PlotLabel -> "Displacement"]}

Issue:
Despite following the paper's methodology closely, the results from my Mathematica implementation do not match the figures presented in Figure 4a and 4b of the paper. Here are the discrepancies I've observed:

Strain Error: The error values in my plots are significantly higher/lower than those reported. In fact it seems as if the solution were diverging.
Deformation: The deformation patterns do not align with the expected results.
Energy and Displacement: There are noticeable differences in the energy and displacement values - the critical g value for phase transition is shifted to higher values in my results when compared to Figure 4a and 4b in the paper.

Questions:

Parameter Scaling: Are there any common pitfalls or mistakes in scaling the parameters ( \mu, \lambda, t, \kappa, g ) that I might have overlooked?
Operator Definitions: Could there be issues with how the operators ( T, H, D, D_x, D_y, B ) are implemented?
SOR Algorithm: Is my implementation of the SOR algorithm correct, and are the initial values for ( u_x, u_y, h ) reasonable? I am not sure the solution is converging.
Comparison with Results: Are there any specific checks or validations I can perform to ensure that my implementation aligns with the theoretical model in the paper?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help resolve these discrepancies. Thank you!


How long does it take your code to generate these drawings?

The drawings are generated from variable SDdata after running for a 2-3 hours (estimation) in a mathematica notebook. Perhaps less computational time if the number of atoms (controlled by nn variable ) is reduced and there are less unknowns.

Your code is very slow. Practically it should be very fast, like 100 s for this test. Also, code is very complicated wile problem looks as very simply.
